# Bokeh server: periodic callback to reload data asynchronously?

Tags: python, server, bokeh

I'd like to schedule a periodic -non blocking- task in my Bokeh Server, such as being able to reload data when necessary (without having to restart the server).

There are functions to schedule periodic tasks, such as [`add_periodic_callback`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/document.html#bokeh.document.document.Document), however it's at the session level (document) and not in the application code.

How can this be performed at the app code level? I don't want each of my sessions to reload the data, which operation needs only be done once and  for all.

I tried using a tornado periodic callback, but I end up having race conditions, as described in this ticket: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4000

```
# example of bad code using Tornado, which creates race condition

...
# see below: my_func_to_reload_data_async() is used to reload data asynchronously

bokeh_server.start()
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback
pcallback = PeriodicCallback(my_func_to_reload_data_async, 3000, io_loop=bokeh_server.io_loop)
pcallback.start()
bokeh_server.io_loop.start()
```

Thanks

Comment: I use curdoc().add_periodic_callback(data_load_func, 86400000) though after the data load, the session does not react anymore and need to be reloaded.